# Unicode support in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, unicode, highlight

I am trying to highlight/bold the match words from string. The following function works fine with English but not with Unicode support. I tried to add `u` for Unicode support in regular expression rule but does not works for me.

```
function highlight_term($text, $words)
{
    preg_match_all('~[A-Za-z0-9_äöüÄÖÜ]+~u', $words, $m);
    if( !$m )
    {
        return $text;
    }

    $re = '~(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')~i';
    return preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
}

$str = "ह ट इ ड यन भ भ और द";

echo highlight_term($str, 'और');
```

Output

> ��� ��� ��� ��� ������ ��� ��� ������ ���

Expected output

> ह ट इ ड यन भ भ **और** द

Comment: You'd better trace your code. I doubt if you read it at all.

Comment: You need `u` in the second regex: `$re = '~' . implode('|', $m[0]) . '~ui';`. No need for the outer parentheses as you are only interested in the whole match value (you replace using `$0` backreference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixing your current approach

Note that you  could change your first regex to `~[\p{L}\p{M}]+~u` to match all Unicode letters (`\p{L}` with `u` modifier becomes Unicode aware and matches any Unicode letters) and diacritics (`\p{M}` matches combining marks) and add a `u` modifier to the second `preg_replace`:

```
function highlight_term($text, $words)
{
    $i = preg_match_all('~[\p{L}\p{M}]+~u', $words, $m);
    if( $i == 0  )
    {
        return $text;
    }

    $re = '~' . implode('|', $m[0]) . '~iu';
    return preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
}

$str = "ह ट इ ड यन भ भ और द";

echo highlight_term($str, 'और');
```

Result: `ह ट इ ड यन भ भ <b>और</b> द`.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/mX8Wd5)

You need `u` modifier in the second regex as the text you pass to the pattern is Unicode and you still work with the Unicode string. No need for the outer parentheses in the second regex as you are only interested in the whole match value (you replace using `$0` backreference).

## Better way

You may pass an array of words to the highlighting function, and match only whole words with word boundaries directly passing the regex to the `preg_replace` function:

```
function highlight_term($text, $words)
{
    return preg_replace('~\b(?:' . implode("|", $words) . ')\b~u', '<b>$0</b>', $text);
}

$str = "ह ट इ ड यन भ भ और द";
echo highlight_term($str, ['और','भ']);
// => ह ट इ ड यन <b>भ</b> <b>भ</b> <b>और</b> द
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/heCT5e)

Comment: @Hassaan: Have a look at the improved approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew both ways took same time to execute, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Hassaan: Maybe, but the second one looks more succint to me. You end up running only one regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But I think, I also need to use `explode` my on my keyword list first to make array of words

Comment: @Hassaan That is not related to this question. Just note that if your "words" may contain special chars, and they can start or end with non-word chars, it is best to use `preg_qupte($wrd, '~')` (use `array_map`) on those exploded words, and replace `\b...\b` with `(?<!\w)...(?!\w)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have done quick benchmarking for both ways and here are results.

1) https://3v4l.org/UolnS/perf
2) https://3v4l.org/F5lsa/perf

Comment: So the latter is more efficient. If you remove `\b` (if you do not need to check word boundaries), it should be even better.